# Using Sass with Meteor

Tags: meteor, sass, materialize

I just added sass via `meteor add fourseven:scss` and am trying to use

```
body {
 @extend .purple;
 @extend .lighten-3;
}
```

from the [materializecss](http://materializecss.com/) package, but im not seeing any results. I've changed the file extension to `.scss`. Any ideas why its not working?

Comment: Are you importing materialize.scss into the scss file above?  If not, are you seeing a console error (server side)?

Answer (score 2):

you have to set the path in scss.json on your root folder. If the json file isn't there, create it. Here is an example of one. Correct paths according to your env

```
{
  "enableAutoprefixer": true,
  "includePaths": [
    "path/to/some/sass/folder",
    "path/to/another/sass/folder",
    "/home/nan/.meteor/packages/materialize_materialize/0.96.1/web.browser/packages/materialize_materialize/bin/materialize.css"
  ]
}
```